# How to refresh WPF web browser

Tags: c#, wpf

I noticed a strange problem with the WebBrowser element. Every time I update a website, after building the application, I had to manually right-click the web browser and click "refresh" to see changed website. How can I make it refresh automaticaly? I'm using blank WPF template.
I have tried to refresh my page via (NewsInfo.Refresh();), but I have only error messenage:

```
    System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
  HResult = 0x80131501
  Message = Invoking the constructor for type "TubbyLauncher.MainWindow" matching the specified binding constraints caused an exception., Line number 6, position 9.
  Source = PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException (Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load (XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml (XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml (Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo (Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent (Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup ()
   at System.Windows.Application. <. ctor> b__1_0 (Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall (Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen (Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl ()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext (Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper (Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run (CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke ()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue ()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook (IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean & handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc (IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean & handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation (Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall (Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen (Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl (DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc (IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage (MSG & msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl (DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame (DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run ()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher (Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal (Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run ()
   at TubbyLauncher.App.Main ()

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    TubbyLauncher.MainWindow.MainWindow () in MainWindow.xaml.cs

Inner Exception 1:
COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TubbyLauncher
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NewsInfo.Refresh();
        }

        private void Frame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void LaunchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Launcher.PlayGame();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Launcher.LaunchDiag("Launcher couldn't find game, please reinstall Slendertubbies.", "Game not found!");
            }
            
        }

        private void Website_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Launcher.LaunchWebstie("https://seba0456.itch.io/slendertubbies/");
        }
    }
}
```

My project:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VM8g7ytZhRgnX1JnIFXB70yjslHBNUve/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `I had to manually right-click the web browser and click "refresh"` yes, of course as that current instance isn't valid anymore. Please use [Refresh Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.refresh?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). What would be the determining factors to make it refresh *automatically*?

Comment: I have no idea how to use "public void Refresh ();". I don;t know where to put this. I have only blank project. If i put this to projet.xaml.cs i have errors:

Comment: You need to use the method itself on the current instance of the webbrowser. Something like `webBrowser.Refresh();` I'm not sure what your browser name is... Also please see my comment again, specifically the last sentence; I can't answer `where to put this` you can only tell us the conditions...

Comment: I apologize for providing haotic information about my problem. I'm new to programming.
I've tried to use webBrowser.Refresh() (I have changed webBrowser to my browser name.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:

    [External Code]
    TubbyLauncher.MainWindow.MainWindow() in MainWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: @seba0456 Two questions: 1) Where does the web browser live in your code? Is it inside the `Launcher` class? 2) Which condition(s) do you want to trigger a browser refresh?

Comment: 1)My web browser isn't inside "Launcher class". Honestly I have no idea how to check where it is :(. Class was created after web browser. 2.) I want to trigger refresh every time app starts.

Comment: @seba0456 Where did `NewsInfo` and `Launcher` come from? Are they classes you wrote? Are they built into .NET? Are they 3rd party libraries?

Comment: NewsInfo is WPF component  was created by drag&drop operation. I have created it from Toolbox , its Web browser. Launcher is class that i wrote.

Comment: I have no idea why, but: NewsInfo.Navigate("https://www.microsoft.com"); works, but NewsInfo.Refresh(); is not working :( I have noticed that my website is saved in app data.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with WPF, but perhaps `Refresh` only works if you've already navigated to a page? (In your code, it's called immediately after `InitializeComponent`, before any page has been loaded.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used:

```
var url = "https://www.microsoft.com";
NewsInfo.Navigate(url + "?refreshToken=" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

Instead:

```
NewsInfo.Refresh();
```